# Existence of minimum of weighted integrals to approximate $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, calculus-of-variations

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a non-zero polynomial of degree $\le n$. Then, note that:

$$\int_0^1\frac{p(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{A}{n!} + \frac{B\ln(2)}{2}+\frac{C\pi}{4}$$

for some integers $A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $p \ge 0 $ on $[0,1]$. Then:

$$\frac{A}{n!} + \frac{B\ln(2)}{2}+\frac{C\pi}{4} \ge 0$$

It is not difficult to find a necessary and sufficient condition on the coefficients of $p$ for $A,C \neq 0, B=0$. Then, we could rearrange to find  a rational inequality for $\pi$, which could be made arbitrarily close if $n$ was allowed to vary. This raises a natural question -- ignoring the constraints on $A,B,C$ for now, which polynomial gives the best bound for fixed $n$?

**Question**: For $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $p \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$ and  $\deg p \le n$, is there a polynomial which minimises $\int_0^1\frac{p(x)}{1+x^2}dx$? If so, is it possible to describe a finite set in which this polynomial must lie (in terms of bounds on coefficients)?

I have only proved the trivial lemma:

$$\int_0^1 p(x) dx > 0 \implies \int_0^1 p(x)dx \ge \frac{1}{n!}$$

Intuitively, it is clear that the coefficients of $p$ cannot be too large, but I have found it difficult to make progress on this question because it is hard to consider both the minimisation w.r.t. $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $p \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$ at the same time. I am also not sure if the result holds in general; if $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ was replaced with an arbitrary weight function $w:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $w > 0$.

Let me know if a different choice of tags would be more appropriate.

Comment: This is still an active research field, see for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06345.pdf

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, I will read it. Would it be possible to summarise what the paper means for this question? I can't immediately see the link to this specific family of integrals.

Comment: With the choice $p(x)=(x(1-x))^4$ you recover the Archimedean approximation $\pi\approx\frac{22}{7}$. The hunt for polynomials (and weight functions) which improve the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is still open. Actually we only know that $\mu(\pi)<7.11$.

Comment: About trivial things, if $|c|$ is the greatest coefficient in absolute value of the polynomial $p$ then $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{p(x)}{1+x^2}dx\leq \frac{|c|\pi}{4}$

Comment: @FDP What about $p(x) = 1+x^2$? Also, for the question, we really need a bound in the other direction.

Comment: @Legionwhale: missing factor $n+1$ in my bound .

Comment: https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Papers/By%20Others/more-pi.pdf would be interesting

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you; the link provides a comprehensive survey of the general idea. It seems that only certain families of polynomials $p$ have been investigated, which is slightly disappointing, as I didn't really expect that this question would not have been solved.